# Dynamic Key Value Array with Multiple Values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I have:

`var data = [];`

I want to dynamically create string array like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++){
    data[i].part1 = "abc";
    data[i].part2 = "def";
    data[i].part3 = "ghi"; 
}
```

Is this possible? I tried it and it complained 'Cannot set property 'part1' of undefined'

Then I want to sort the data array by part1 values so:

```
data[0] = {3,a,b};
data[1] = {1,a,b};
data[2] = {5,a,b};
```

becomes:

```
data[0] = {1,a,b,c};
data[1] = {3,a,b,c};
data[2] = {5,a,b,c};
```

The reason I want to do this is because after the sort is done, i need to change the

data[i].part2

to something else after sorting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    data[i] = {};
    data[i].part1 = "abc";
    data[i].part2 = "def";
    data[i].part3 = "ghi"; 
}
```

to set `data[i]` to an empty object, then fill it piece by piece. Or

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    data[i] = {
        part1: "abc",
        part2: "def",
        part3: "ghi"
    };
}
```

to set `data[i]` to the complete object all at once.

---

I don't understand the `data[0] = {3,a,b};` part, though: `{3,a,b}` is a syntax error and it doesn't resemble your other code (which doesn't mention `3` or `a` or `b`).

But you can easily sort an array of objects by a particular property:

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.part1 > b.part1) - (a.part1 < b.part1);
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort for details.